# Уведомления в Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, service, уведомления

Допустим есть простенький чат созданный на Firebase. Пользователь авторизуется через email и пароль, после этого попадает на экран, где выводится список всех сообщений из бд. Так вот как сделать, чтобы приложение в фоне проверяло новые сообщения в бд и посылало телефону обычные уведомления в статус бар. Для работы в фоне знаю надо использовать Service. Но как понять, что пришло новое сообщение? И как прослушивать в фоне базу данных Firebase, есть для этого какой-нибудь специальный слушатель? Какие есть идеи?

Comment: В рамках Firebase для этого можно использовать FCM + Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 1):

в гугле по запросу firebase android chat есть примеры как на русском, и английском. [вот один из них](https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397).

чтобы сделать уведомление, вам нужно сделать `dataBaseReference.addChildEventListener`, как показано [здесь](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data).

а теперь меджик: чтобы получать сообщения, когда активити свёрнута, `addChildEventListener` нужно добавлять в [забинденном сервисе](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services?hl=ru), из которого и будут сыпаться [уведомления](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications?hl=ru), а по нажатию на уведомление сервис кидает данные в Ваше активити, например, через [intent](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity).